# There's no value when searching in date range

Tags: java, hibernate, model-view-controller, hql

Why is there no value when i am searching the date range in JAVA MVC using hibernate.
In mysql for testing there's a value but when i am about to search using the application, there's no result.
What's wrong with my code?

MODEL:

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
     private Date deliveryDate;
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    private LocalDate startDt;
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)  
    private LocalDate endDt;
    
    
    
    public LocalDate getStartDt() {
        return startDt;
    }
    public void setStartDt(LocalDate startDt) {
        this.startDt = startDt;
    }
    public LocalDate getEndDt() {
        return endDt;
    }
    public void setEndDt(LocalDate endDt) {
        this.endDt = endDt;
    }
```

VIEW:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><b>SEARCH</b></button>
                        <form>
                        from <form:input path="startDt" name= "search"  type= "date" style="box-sizing:border-box; height:30px;"/>
                        to <form:input path="endDt"  name= "search" type= "date"  style="box-sizing:border-box; height:30px"/>
                        <input type= "submit" class="btn btn-success" style=height:30px;/>
                        </form>
                        
                        <%-- <a class = "btn btn-primary" href = "<c:url value="/inventory/secured/admin/inventory/master/formAddItem"/>" ><b>CREATE</b></a> --%>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <%-- <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<c:url value="/inventory/secured/admin/inventory/master/form"/>">CREATE</a> --%>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

DAO/HIBERNATE

```
         if(sched.getStartDt()!=null && sched.getEndDt()!=null){
                dynamicSql.append("and DATE_FORMAT(ds.deliveryDate,'%y-%M-%d') between (:startDt) AND (:endDt)) ");
            }
```

```
if(sched.getStartDt()!=null && sched.getEndDt()!=null){
            query.setParameter("startDt","%"+sched.getStartDt()+"%").setParameter("endDt","%"+ sched.getEndDt()+"%");
            queryCount.setParameter("startDt", "%"+sched.getStartDt()+"%");
            queryCount.setParameter("endDt", "%"+sched.getEndDt()+"%");
         }
```